# scrapy crawl urls retrieved

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this snippet of a spider in scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from infoseeker.items import InfoseekerItem as InfoItem



class SeekerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'seeker'
    allowed_domains = ['info.mzalendo.com']
    start_urls = ['http://info.mzalendo.com/position/member-national-assembly/?page=1']
    main_url = 'http://info.mzalendo.com/position/member-national-assembly/'
    urls = []
    retrieving = False

    def parse(self, response):
        if not self.retrieving:
            selector_list = response.css('.position')

            for selector in selector_list:
                self.urls.append(selector.css('a::attr(href)').extract()[0])

            found = response.css('.next::attr(href)').extract()
            if found:
                next_page = self.main_url + found[0] #uses ?page=2, ?page=3 format so appended to main url to avoid issues
            else:
                next_page = None

            if next_page is not None:
                yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
            else:
                self.retrieving = True

        #should run once all urls have been found
        for url in self.urls:
            pass #get content for url to be parsed
```

since the content I want to query are listed on pages, first I've queried all the pages and retrieved the list of urls and stored them in `self.urls` what I intend to do once this process is complete is start querying the urls to now retrieve the useful info.

Not sure if `yield` would be the suitable command to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is **callback**. To call another functions which will take care of the url's which you are trying to scrape.

> CALLBACK (callable) – the function that will be called with the response of this request (once its downloaded) as its first parameter. For more information see Passing additional data to callback functions below. If a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s parse() method will be

[Here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions), like this

```
import .....

class SeekerSpider(CrawlSpider):

name = 'seeker'
allowed_domains = ['info.mzalendo.com']
start_urls = ['http://info.mzalendo.com/position/member-national-assembly/?page=1']
main_url = 'http://info.mzalendo.com/position/member-national-assembly/'
urls = []
retrieving = False

def parse(self, response):
    .......
    #  All the above code in between.
    .......

    #should run once all urls have been found
    for url in self.urls:
        #get content for url to be parsed. USE CALLBACK
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_url)

def parse_url(self, response):
    #Do whatever you want with the response of desired url.
```